# How to sort a List containing lists of the same size in the asscending order of thier numerical value in java

Tags: java, list, sorting, data-structures, collections

```
     public static void main(String args[])
{
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<List<Integer>> masterList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    
    list1.add(3);
    list1.add(7);
    
    list2.add(1);
    list2.add(9);
    
    list3.add(5);
    list3.add(4);
    
    
    masterList.add(list3);
    masterList.add(list1);
    masterList.add(list2);
}
```

**Which is the easiest way to sort a list containing lists of integer type in the ascending order of their numerical values java at the beginner level?
like I have a list containing list [ [1,9], [5,4], [3,7] ] the order should be [ [5,4],[3,7],[1,9] ] because 54>37>19**

Comment: Hello. Please [edit] your question and clarify in what way you want to sort them (post example of input, result, and logic behind that result)? For instance if you have lists like `[ [1,9], [5,4], [3,7] ]` what should be result? For instance should we order them based *only* on their second element like `[ [5,4], [3,7], [1,9] ]`? OR maybe based on their *middle* element (if such exist)? Or based on *average* of elements in list?

Comment: `[ [5,4],[3,7],[1,9] ] because 54>37>19` suggest that you want to *combine* all "digits" into single number and compare those numbers. But do we have guarantee that each list will only hold "digits" or can there also be numbers built from many digits? So is it possible to have lists like `[12, 345]` and `[123, 45]`? If YES then what should be result here? Notice that after combining elements from both list will result in number 12345 so they would be equal, which means we shouldn't swap those lists. But is that really your intention?

Comment: Can you have negative values?  How would you combine `[1,-5]` vs `[-1,5]`? And you say `ascending` but your example is `descending`.

Answer (score -2):

```
package extra;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

class ListSort implements Comparator<List<Integer>>  //Comparator type List<Integer>
{
    public int compare(List<Integer> a,List<Integer> b)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
        {
            if(a.get(i)<b.get(i))
            {
                return -1;   // -ve value if a is less than b
            }
            else if(a.get(i)>b.get(i))
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        
        return 0;  // return 0 if lists are identical
    }
}

public class SortingLists {
    
    
public static void main(String args[])
{
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<List<Integer>> masterList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    

    list1.add(3);
    list1.add(7);
    
    list2.add(1);
    list2.add(9);
    
    list3.add(5);
    list3.add(4);
    
    
    masterList.add(list3);
    masterList.add(list1);
    masterList.add(list2);
    
    Collections.sort(masterList,new ListSort());
    System.out.println(masterList);
    
    
}
}
```

Comment: An answer should include an explanation. If it helps to add some code, do so. Just 'boom, here you go' is not an appropriate answer. Especially if the code provided uses all sorts of dubious style constructions.